# Celery Task with Queue Payload

Tags: python, celery

I am new on Celery. I try to publish a message to a queue and try to read it.

My code looks:

app.py:

```
from celery import Celery
from kombu import Queue

config = {
    "broker_url": 'amqp://guest:guest@localhost/guest',
    "broker_pool_limit": 1,
    "result_backend": None,
    "broker_heartbeat": None,
    "task_ignore_result": True,
    "event_queue_expires": 60,
    "broker_connection_timeout": 40,
    "worker_prefetch_multiplier": 1,
    "worker_concurrency": 2,
    "worker_hijack_root_logger": False,
    "worker_max_tasks_per_child": 10,
    "reject_on_worker_lost": True,
    "buffer_while_offline": False
}
celery = Celery("tasks", broker=config["broker_url"])
celery.conf.update(**config)
celery.task_acks_late = True
celery.conf.broker_transport_options = {}

celery.conf.task_queues = (Queue('test_queue', routing_key='tasks.test_task',
                                 **{'x-queue-mode': 'lazy', 'queue_arguments': {'x-queue-mode': 'lazy'}}),
                           )
```

tasks.py:
from app import celery

```
@celery.task(name='tasks.test_task')
def hello(to):
    print(to)
    return to
```

and run application with: `celery -A app worker --without-heartbeat --without-gossip --without-mingle --loglevel=debug -Ofair -P threads`

But when I publish a message from rabbitmq:
[image]

it says: **WARNING/MainProcess] Received and deleted unknown message.  Wrong destination?!?**

Any suggestion? It is so basic example.

Comment: Is invoking the task though python interface not possible? For example https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/getting-started/first-steps-with-celery.html#calling-the-task